# Triple Pivot Challenge

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the following challenge, trying to join 3 tables in Laravel 5:

I have a many-to-many relation between 3 table: students, classrooms, terms. I would love to make a call like `term->classroom->students`.

I saw the Eloquent-triple-pivot package, but unfortunately, I cant get it working for Laravel 5.

Please, I would appreciate solution to bind this and make the call, eloquent or otherwise.

Thank you.

**EDIT**:

I have **many-to-many relationship** between 3 tables; classrooms, students, terms.

I have 3 pivot tables: classroom_term, classroom_student, student_term.

And 3 corresponding models: ClassroomTerm, ClassroomStudent, StudentTerm.

My **Classroom** model:

```
 public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student')->withTimestamps();
}
public function terms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Term')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My **Term** Model:

```
public function classrooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classroom')->withTimestamps();
}
public function students()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student')->withTimestamps();
}
```

My **Student** model:

```
public function terms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Term')->withTimestamps();
}
public function classrooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Classroom')->withTimestamps();
}
```

What I am doing in my **StudentsController** is

```
$term = Term::findOrFail($id);
foreach($term->classrooms as $classroom) {
$studentids = ClassroomStudent::where('classroom_id', '=', $classroom->id)->get();
}
//to get the real student collection
foreach($studentids->student_id as $studentid){
$students = Student::findOrFail($studentid)
}
return view('students.list')->with(['students' => $students]);
```

In my **students.list** view, I would simply want to retrieve students:

```
@foreach($students as $student)
First Name: {{!!$student->first_name!!}}
@endforeach
```

The error is in this line:

```
foreach($studentids->student_id as $studentid){
$students = Student::findOrFail($studentid)
}

Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$student_id'
```

However dd($studentids) returned an array and one of the attributes is student_id.

The code is cumbersome and not working.
Thanks for your help

**The Goal**:
To retrieve the students in the classroom in the term.  With many-to-many relationship between classrooms, students and terms.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? and what is your code..? becouse you cant simply do `term->classroom->students` you first do `term->classroom` loop it trough an `foreach` and do `classroom->students`. many to many returns an array

Comment: @Joost please, check my comments. Thanks for your further clarification.

Comment: If you show us your table fields, we could help you better

Answer (score -1):

An many to many relation returns an array which it still does when you define the sudentids `->get()` also returns an array only `->first()` would not return an array but then you do not get all students.
A variable does not turn in an array automatically making your foreach only return the last value.
So to correctly return the values from the students you would most likely get something like this.

Controller:

```
// Or even bind the term to the url
$term = Term::findOrFail($id);
return view('students.list',compact("term"));
```

View:

```
<!-- You could even remove the classroom name/list around it if you purely want to display all students under the term -->
<li>
    @foreach($term->classrooms as $classroom) {

        <ul>
            Classroom: {{ $classroom->name }}
            <li>
                @foreach($classroom->students as $student)
                    <ul>
                        First name: {{ $student->first_name }}
                    </ul>
                @endforeach
            </li>
        </ul>

    @endforeach
</li>
```

Another simple way to return all students under a term is using the ->whereHas() in your query doing this would be enough

Controller:

```
$students = Student::whereHas("classrooms",function($q){
        $q->whereHas("terms",function($q){
            $q->where("id",$termId);
        });
    })->get();
return view('students.lists',compact("students"));
```

View:

```
<li>
    @foreach($students as $student)
        <ul>
            First name: {{ $student->first_name }}
        </ul>
    @endforeach
</li>
```

If you want to return specific classrooms within a term or even a user under both you should create 3 controllers one for each of them (only 2 if you do not want to display students separate) and nest your classrooms under terms so you can simply type `/terms/1/classrooms/2/` to get the right classroom or `/terms/1/classrooms` to get all classrooms under a term.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could be setting the relations not well. Try thinking it well, for example, I think that probably a Student `belongsTo` a Classroom.

### Classroom Model

```
 public function students()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Student')->withTimestamps();
}


public function terms()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Term')->withTimestamps();
}
```

### Term Model:

```
public function classrooms()
{
     return $this->hasMany('App\Classroom')->withTimestamps();
}
```

### Student model:

```
 public function classrooms()  
 {
     return $this->belongsTo('App\Classroom')->withTimestamps();
 }
```